# Need help integrating existing app with turn-based multiplayer in google play

Tags: android, google-play-services

About a month ago I completed a purely offline chess application. The chess app was rather simple and only used one activity.

After google revealed their new turn-based multiplayer api I decided to change my chess app to make it work online using this turn based multiplayer. However, I am having some trouble.

Everything I have been reading doesn't really tell you how your code should flow. So far my app has the google sign in button and when you press play it will take you to a lobby where you can invite people but I dont know what im supposed to do when the game starts.

Any advice about the general flow of my code would be appreciated. Eg, how do I take the turn? How do I make sure you cant make a move when its not your turn? How do I update the games data after each turn.

I know this question reads like I havnt done any research but I really have and I am completely lost. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for online turn based game play or asynchronous turn based game play?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am implementing this into one of my games.  I use state transition based programming in a game loop.  So you can change the game state and then different code will run.  Using this method, I then build a state for PlayingMultiplayer and WaitingMultiplayer based upon the return code of getTurnStatus().  In Playing, I will get the player's turn, then persist the data and switch to Waiting.  In Waiting I just periodically poll for a change to getTurnStatus and when it detects a change, I switch the state back to Playing.   Rinse and repeat until Game End.

Comment: I already finished this app but this answer is still good. :)